# How to recover an overriten partition?

Tags: data-recovery, dd, undelete

So I thought I try something fancy today and learn how to use the terminal to install a raspberry pi image on a flash drive. The result was not as I imagined.

Apparently I've overwritten my partition containing / and all the important stuff.
Which I've only realised after starting my pc up again. (I didn't noticed it for 5h)

The only folders I've left on a different partition are:

- bin
- include
- lib
- locale
- packages
- sbin
- share
- src

So I would like to know if it's possible to recover my partition containing / and family, due to me not having a backup flying around, and as so often it contains somewhat important data.

The partition was in encrypted, so idk if that makes it harder or easier to recover. (I've still got the password, so that at least should be an issue)

Comment: I cannot imagine how encryption would make data recovery *easier*.

Comment: @user535733 yeah I think so too, I hope it doesn't make it harder.

Comment: It makes it impossible when overwritten, even if only partially. Without encryption some files could be recovered if not actually overwritten but with the encryption you'd need to recover all that just as it was and absolutely pristine. So, impossible.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I thought so, lesson learned tripple check the path names if using dd and commiting every day on Github regardless how far I came + monthly Backups.